# Writing code with OFTInteger data type in OGR/GDAL?

Tags: shapefile, gdal, ogr

I created the shapefile by using the feature field type: OFTInteger.

But when I open the shapefile in Arcgis (ArcCatalog) the data type is: **Double (not integer)**.

Do you know how to fix this (I want it is Int) ?

Please see my codes:

```
OGRFieldDefn oSHToBDField( "SHBANDO", OFTInteger);
poSHPLayer->CreateField (&oSHToBDField);
```